# Program to search for a keyword in the services' descriptions

Tags: windows, gratis

I was trying to find services that take care of [USB ports](https://superuser.com/q/84753/116475) and it was painful to look through the services' descriptions:

[image]

I am looking for a program having the following features:

- Can search for a keyword in the services' descriptions (and ideally search in the service's name field too)
- Works on Windows 7
- If possible: is free and has a GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply export the list of services:

[image]

The exported list is a column-separated values that includes the description, which you can easily search:

```
Name    Description Status      Startup Type    Log On As
ActiveX Installer (AxInstSV)    Provides User Account Control validation for the installation of ActiveX controls from the Internet and enables management of ActiveX control installation based on Group Policy settings. This service is started on demand and if disabled the installation of ActiveX controls will behave according to default browser settings.        Manual  Local System
Adaptive Brightness Monitors ambient light sensors to detect changes in ambient light and adjust the display brightness.  If this service is stopped or disabled, the display brightness will not adapt to lighting conditions.     Manual  Local Service
Adobe Acrobat Update Service    Adobe Acrobat Updater keeps your Adobe software up to date. Started Automatic   Local System
Application Experience  Processes application compatibility cache requests for applications as they are launched        Manual  Local System
Application Identity    Determines and verifies the identity of an application. Disabling this service will prevent AppLocker from being enforced.      Manual  Local Service
```